# Filtering array elements then joining each into a single string

Tags: javascript, for-loop, replace

I have array `myArr = ['a_file1.js', 'b_file2.js', 'c_file3.js']` going through a **for loop** with **the goal of returning** `myStr = 'file1 file2 file3'`

```
const myArr = ['a_file1.js', 'b_file2.js', 'c_file3.js']

const toFilterOut = ['a', 'b', 'c', '_', '.js', ',']

let myStr = myArr;


for (i = 0; i < toFilterOut.length; i++) {

  myStr = myStr.toString().replace(toFilterOut[i], '');

}

console.log(myStr.join(' '))
```

This block returns `Uncaught TypeError: myStr.join is not a function`

> How can I convert `myArr` into a single string (accounting for **each element inside**), to then properly filter it out then join in back together as a filtered string

Comment: well myStr is a string `myStr = myStr.toString()....`

Comment: _"This block returns..."_ - Because at that point `myStr` is (as the name correctly suggests) a string and not an array. And strings don't have a `.join()` method

Comment: `myStr = myStr.replace(unwantedWords[i], '');` returns not a function which is where i get confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code you are setting myStr to a string. And a string does not have a join method. Your code only replaces the first match, it is not going to do what you want.

Using a regular expression to match a pattern would be a lot cleaner.

```js
const myArr = ['a_file1.js', 'b_file2.js', 'c_file3.js']

var result = myArr.map( val => val.match(/^[abc]_(.*)\.js$/)[1])
// var result = myArr.map(function (val) { return val.match(/^[abc]_(.*)\.js$/)[1] })

console.log(result.join(' '))
```

Comment: Or `.split(/_|\./)[1]`

Comment: Thanks! Still very new to ES6, did not know this could be done in one line

Comment: @Andreas only downside to that is if the filename contains any of those.